# erro : problema ao realizar npm start , failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script - React

Tags: react, npm, packages, módulo-ecmascript

Estou tentando rodar meu app em React pelo comando `npm start` , mas toda vez aparece isso:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000007AEDF1DEE0npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Eu ja acessei alguns forum , ja tentei excluir o node_modules e o package-lock.json e reinstala-los , dar update no npm , instalar o react-scripts@2.1.8 , mas nada disso funciona , alguém tem alguma idéia ? Obrigado

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960890/6797930 tente essa resposta

Comment: ja tentei  ,foi uma das primeiras que achei , mas n foi

Answer (score 1):

Tive o mesmo problema.

Consegui resolver fazendo:

- `npm install -g npm@latest` para atualizar o npm
- `rm -rf node_modules` para remover todos os modulos existentes
- `npm install` para re-instalar as dependencias do projeto.

**Obs.:** No meu caso eu instalei o npm@latest sem usar o `-g` (global)

Depois rodei o `npm run build` e `npm start`.

---

Com isso, apareceu erro no node-sass, entao rodei:

- `npm uninstall node-sass`
- `npm install node-sass@4.14.1 --save`

Faça isso para todas as dependências que apresentarem error.

---

Conforme feito aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959900/npm-start-error-with-create-react-app/39960890#39960890